# Adding a column at the parent or at the child in a Table-Per-Type (TPT) inheritance

Tags: database-design

have different types of assets , some of the assets that are technology-based should have a IP column and this IP should be unique. But non-technology asset will not even have IP column. Currently I am storing the data as follow:-
[image]

But I am not sure where to store the IP address, I have the following approaches:-

1. Store it in the “Asset” parent table , so I can set it as a unique key and guarantee that no technology-based asset will have the same IP. But the drawback is that the IP column will be always be null for all the non-technological assets.
2. The second approach; is to add an IP column to each technology-based table. This will prevent null values , but need custom work to guarantee unique. as I can guarantee uniqueness only per table and not for all the technology-based assets..

So can anyone advice on which approach I should follow OR there is another approach I am not aware of?

BR

**:::EDIT:::**

I have currently the following database structure:-
[image]

Currently I see these points:-

1. I have introduced a redundant AssetTypeID column in the base Asset table, so I can know the asset type without having to join tables. This might break normalization.
2. In my above architecture , I cannot control (on the database level) which asset should have IP, which asset should not have IP and which asset can/cannot have multiple IPs. So is there a way to improve my architecture to handle these two points.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You could create another table `TechnologyAsset` that inherits from `Asset`. Then `Servers` and `Router` can inherit from `TechonlogyAsset`.</strike>

**EDIT:**

Your second comment changes things entirely. Neither of the options you presented would allow multiple IP Addresses to a single asset. In that case you should create an `IPAddresses` table, which then has a foreign key to `Asset`. This way you can have zero, one or multiple IPAddresses for a given asset.

**Second edit:**

With regards to point #1, yes it can lead to corrupted or invalid data. There's an inherent trade off between performance and error-proofing. Indexing can help with performance and still maintain normalization, but you won't beat the performance of adding that TypeId with all the indices in the world.

With regards to point #2, I think it would be fairly difficult to maintain uniqueness of IPs while forcing some assets to have 1 IP, some to have 0, and others the ability to have multiple from an architecture perspective. I was drawing something up, but it would be a real pain to query, and insert, never mind updates.

I would suggest enforcing such rules through application business rules, stored procedures, etc..

Comment: to be honest i did not do this kind of multiple inheritance before ? but is it a best practice in relational databases to have this kind of multi-level inheritance ?

Comment: and some assets which i did not display might have multiple IP addresses related to them.

Comment: you are right,, can you see my edit and the new database diagram i have. the new diagram will solve the uniqueness of the IP address . but created some other issues..